# How do I get user jars to take precedence over hadoop jars, for oozie, using hadoop 1.3

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am using hadoop 1.3 and oozie. My java action refers to a method commons-collection 1.7. which is not present in previous version. The jar is a fat jar with all the classes, which I put in the lib folder under my workflow. OOzie when it starts my submit action refers to an older hadoop jar which is on the classpath rather than giving the user jars precedence. Is there any way that the user jars can be given precedence? oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence=true  will not work as this is hadoop 1.3 not hadoop2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Maven one approach would be to shade the problematic classes within your jar using the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html). This will transparently rename the classes within your jar so that they do not clash with different versions of the same classes that are otherwise put on the classpath by Oozie or Hadoop.

Comment: That is so unfortunate that we have to resort to build time trickery to get things to work. Thanks Jeremy